# Dynamic SQL / SQL Loops / Dynamic Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I posted a crazy long question last night that was way too in depth. So lets keep this one more theoretical.

Say you have a really long SELECT statement that comprises of dozens of blocks of code. Each block creates a slightly different calculated column. To keep things simple you've named each block after a colour.

You also have 5 variables declared at the top. Each variable contains a colour as a string.

Is it possible to loop through those variables and use the value inside to chose which blocks in the SELECT statement to run?

So the query would return 3 calculated columns. The Green column, Yellow, then Green again, and nothing else as variables 4 & 5 were empty

```
DECLARE

@variable1 = 'Green'
@variable2 = 'Yellow'
@variable3 = 'Green'
@variable4 =  NULL
@variable5 = NULL

SELECT

CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Red Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Yellow Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Pink Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Green Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Orange Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Purple Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Blue Column'

FROM Some_tables

WHERE something = something

ORDER BY
```

Is that even possible with SQL? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Looking at this, and the previous question, you've fallen into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) rabbit hole. You're focused on the problems you're having implementing the solution you've decided on, when you should really be taking a step back and telling us more about the problem your code is supposed to address. Take a breath, read this really good post, [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then come back at it with fresh eyes.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'm using SSMS V17.7 and SQL server 2008. Thanks

Comment: @EricBrandt I have no doubt I'm approaching the problem all wrong. It's just hard to convey when I'm so far off base. Ok, taking a breath and off to read the article you sent about posting on public forums...

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 steps: 
1. insert all the data into intermediate table Tmp1

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Red Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Yellow Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Pink Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Green Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Orange Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Purple Column',
CASE WHEN... THEN... AS 'Blue Column'
Into Tmp1 
FROM Some_tables
```

2. Dynamic select form Tmp1 Table

```
@sql = 'select '
if(@variable1 is not null)
begin 
  @sql= @sql + @variable1  + ' , '
end 

if(@variable2 is not null)
begin 
  @sql= @sql + @variable2  + ' , '
end 
 .......
.......
@sql = left(@sql ,len(@sql)-1)  -- this to remove last ","
@sql = @sql  + ' from Tmp1'
```